# Start and assign an approval task to all users in the given department(s)

Tags: list, lookup-column, list-form, approval-process

I have a form containing a multi-select "Departments" column. I would like the user to be able to check off which departments the list pertains to, so that when the list is submitted for approval, all users associated with the pertinent departments are included in the workflow task.

How would I go about creating a lookup (preferably, non-programatically) that does this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Take user input for selected Department.
2. Maintain a separate master list for department approvers.
3. Associate department approvers with each list item for corresponding departments.
4. In approval workflow attach the task of a list item with that list related department approver.

I hope it will help you in creating a form as per you requirement.